# Show or log long queries with values instead placeholders

Tags: postgresql, sql, debugging, query

I have any very long sql query in postgresql. I tried show what postgress do with:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

unfortunately I see something like:

```
select some_fields from anytable1 anytable2 where \
( anyfield1.anytable1=$1 )and( anyfield2.anytable2=$2 );
```

Is it possible to show what values are replacing parameters $1 $2  ?
It is not important, it can be log file or any sql command.
I must debug it because something is terminating. this is long query and I want to test it manually.